# What is difference Qt.matrix4x4 and QMatrix4x4?

Tags: qt, qml, qt3d

I am learning the Qt 3D module. I found the `Qt.matrix4x4` provide different API than `QMatrix4x4` in C++ side (by using `F1` check the API doc).
look likes `Qt.matrix4x4`  don't have such `scale`  or `rotation` operations. even not in autocomplete.
[image: 0ddff2d6-092d-4dda-95eb-fd695300be0f-image.png] 
BUT! these functions do exist and work!

```
var m = Qt.matrix4x4(1, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 1)
m.scale(2)
console.log(m)
// qml: QMatrix4x4(2, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 1)
// the type shows QMatrix4x4
```

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmatrix4x4.html vs https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-matrix4x4.html

I understand what these is, But why the API show different in API doc and autocomplete?

Comment: The QML type matrix4x4 supports more operations on it, especially `rotate(angleInDegrees, axisVector3d), translate(vector3d), scale(vector3d)`. But the docs are no help. I ended up looking into all QML files provided by Qt to find out how to do certain things.

Comment: You may have a deeper look into the Qt source file `qt\src\qt3d\src\quick3d\quick3d\qt3dquickvaluetypes_p.h` for the 3D basic math types. Everything that is prefixed with Q_INVOKABLE can be called from QML.

Comment: @vre Yes, I saw the source code, there is no `scale` function, but why it works?

Comment: There is. Hidden under `Quick3DMatrix4x4ValueType`.

Comment: @vre I don't think it is hidden under `Quick3DMatrix4x4ValueType`. it works because of https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt3d.git/tree/src/quick3d/quick3d/qt3dquick_global.cpp#n269 the matrix4x4 JS var is actually QMatrix4x4. But I still don't understand why.

Comment: Internally it is handled as QMatrix4x4, you are right. But the `Quick3DMatrix4x4ValueType` metaObj defines the interface that can be accessed from QML.

Answer (score 1):

It is interesting to note that in Qt6 the documentation appears different than Qt5. In Qt6 we see clearly there are methods for constructing the matrix4x4 basic type from a vector and for multiplying them with vectors.

```
// translate(vector3d)
var m = Qt.matrix4x4();
m.translate(Qt.vector3d(1,2,3));
console.log(m.toString());
// QMatrix4x4(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1)

// matrix multiplication
var m = Qt.matrix4x4();
m.translate(Qt.vector3d(1,2,3));
console.log(m.toString());
// QMatrix4x4(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1)

// applying a matrix to a vector
var a = Qt.matrix4x4(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16);
var b = Qt.vector3d(5,6,7);
var c = a.times(b);
console.log(c.toString()); // QVector3D(0.155556, 0.437037, 0.718518)
```

Note I tried all of the above in Qt5.15.6 but it doesn't work. So it appears that support for this type really kicks in at Qt6.

For further information see: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-matrix4x4.html